# Ubuntu 14.04 won't install on boot SSD

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, system-installation, ssd

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my laptop but it doesn't detect the boot SSD. I have an alienware m14x. I exchanged the HDD for a 120GB SSD and then replaced the disk drive with the original 750 HDD for storage. It has Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit installed on the SSD boot drive but when I boot up from USB with Ubuntu it says I have no OS installed and will only show the 750GB HDD.

When I click Try Ubuntu it does however show the SSD drive on the desktop. I have installed on the 750 HDD but then it will only boot to Ubuntu and no options are present to boot to Windows. I have taken the HDD out and it just says you have two HDD's installed. So now I'm stuck. Any help very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is Windows in UEFI or BIOS boot mode? And is Windows hibernated or needing chkdsk as you resized it? Or was SSD partitioned with gpt before and you installed Windows 7 in BIOS boot mode converting drive from gpt to MBR and Windows does not correctly do that?

Comment: Its in BIOS, I have not resized the disk, just installed windows its runs fine just when I try to install unbuntu it does not see the ssd, just the hdd

Comment: Post this from terminal in live installer, just to see some basics. sudo parted -l

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I ended up removing the hdd, leaving just a single SATA device - the SSD - in the computer and installing Ubuntu on it. Once this is done I added the hdd back in place.

Comment: Tried that, still does not see the ssd